# describing snapshots whose associated volume is deleted or not present currently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, snapshot

I was trying to do cost optimisation for my aws account. And i came across the snapshots count. and I saw lots of snapshots over there in my console.

There are some snapshots which were created via any volume. and now the volume is deleted.

How can I describe the snapshots whose volume is not present. ( I know we can use ec2-describe-snapshots, but I need the filters and way to get it.)

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create a lambda function with this code and have it executed by CloudWatch Events daily, this way you clean up regularly without having to remember! ;)

I am going to reference the node.js API here but the method in the madness is the same for all APIs.

1. Use ec2 describeSnapshots to get your collection for iteration (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeSnapshots-property)
2. For each snapshot, call describeVolume using the VolumeId in the Snapshot result as the VolumeId. If it doesn't exist anymore you will get an error. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeVolumes-property)
3. Call deleteSnapshot to delete the snapshot that you no longer need (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#deleteSnapshot-property)

Should be a fun little project! :)